# Не работает https на хостинге jino

Tags: хостинг, vps

На хостинге jino, я приобрел на домен SSL сертификат и включил HTTPS. Но после переноса на VPS, через https сайт перестал работать (самого сайта не видит), а если зайти через http, то сайт откроется. В чем может быть проблема? Я пробовал удалить и заново получить SSL сертификат, не получилось.

Comment: Сам сертификат то Вы перенесли? В `apache2` или `nginx` пути добавили?

Comment: переносил на vps ради websocket. Установил "пакеты приложений" только nodejs. А веб-сервер nginx я не выбрал. Надо выбрать?

Comment: и я так понял, что на нем apache стоит

Comment: Вы сами сертификаты скопировали на сервер? Сервер linux?

Comment: Я изначально домен покупал в основной панели хостинга. После я у этого хостинга арендовал vps. И перенес место хранения файлов сайта на vps. Я начал что-то делать и через час у меня перестал работать https. Да, linux, образ CentOS 7

Comment: А сертификат получил в панели домена Let's Encrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Откройте Ваш сервер и зайдите в папку `/etc/ssl` тут должны находиться Ваши сертификаты. Посмотрите есть ли там они. И те ли, которые устанавливали.
2. Откройте `apache2` - `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` Найдите записи. 
   Выглядеть она должна следующим образом:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName yoursite.ru
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory "/var/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex /index.php
        </Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/chain.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Где `yoursite.ru`- это ваш сайт. 
`DocumentRoot` - это путь к входящему файлу index
`DirectoryIndex` - устанавливается, если входящий файл не `index.html`, 
а `index.php` (если у Вас `index.html`, то соответственно замените `index.php` на `index.html`

`SSLCertificateFile` - Путь к основному сертификату.
`SSLCertificateKeyFile` - Путь к ключу сертификата
`SSLCertificateChainFile` - Путь к цепочке сертификатов.

Обязательно проверьте Что стоит 443 порт `<VirtualHost *:443>`
Если сертификаты точно лежат в нужном месте 
В apache2 точно прописаны пути к ним 
Eсли записть apache2 есть на 445 порт

То у Вас всё должно работать замечательно.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, что лучше выбрать centOS или Ubuntu? Т.к. в каталоге etc/ssl, там нет ничего кроме папки "certs".  А во втором варианте, нету такой пути: apache2 - /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: @Stas В вашем случае на CentOS посмотрите сертификаты дополнительно в папке `/etc/pki/`. Если их и там нет, то их надо будет найти. Apache Смотрите по пути `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

Comment: В папке /etc/pki/ есть папки certs, misc, privare (пустой) и файлы cert.pem, openssl.cnf. А в папке /etc/httpd/conf.d/ есть файлы [название сайта].conf, autoindex.conf, domains.conf и userdir.conf

Comment: @Stas 1. Для начала надо найти Ваши сертификаты. Попробуйте сначала открыть файл [название сайта].conf или domains.conf в них ищите запись, как в моём ответе. 2. В папке /etc/pki/certs посмотрите сертификаты, которые Вы создавали ранее.

Comment: в [название сайта].conf такая структура:

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
        ServerName yoursite.ru
        ServerAlias *.yoursite.ru
        CustomLog   /var/log/httpd/yoursite.ru.access_log combined
        ErrorLog    /var/log/httpd/yoursite.ru.error_log
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/yoursite.ru
</VirtualHost>

Comment: А в domains.conf:

LoadModule php7_module     modules/libphp7.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.phtml
AccessFileName .htaccess
AddDefaultCharset OFF

Comment: @Stas В первом файле ищите запись с портом 443, как в примере. Ищите ту запись, где `ServerName` соответствует Вашему сайту.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104804/discussion-between-stas-and-denis640kb).